# getting from email address when using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i want to show user from which account he is going to send email when he is going to send an email using my app and i am using MFMailComposeViewController. so what is the way of getting the from email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get this information. Mail sent via `MFMailComposeViewController` is always sent from the user's default address.

Answer (score 0):

> Mail sent via `MFMailComposeViewController` is always sent from the user's default address.

User's default address is selected by default but the user can switch the accounts. Anyway, no way to get this info back into your app.